# How to avoid overfitting in deep learning when features are binary in nature

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am constructing a deep learning model using 2048 bits of binary fingerprints (0 and 1's) for some 2000 samples to predict their outputs (positive (1) OR negative(0)). The feature data is quite sparse i.e. lots of zeros and rare 1's.
I have used 'binary cross entropy' but my validation accuracy doesn't increase more than 70%. I have balanced data. The model seems to be overfitting. I can't normalize my data since fetures are binary. How can I avoid overfitting?

```
    earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=20, mode='max')
    final_model = Sequential()
    final_model.add(Dense(1012, input_dim=2048, activation = 'relu'))
    final_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    final_model.add(Dropout(0.9))
    final_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    final_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    final_model.add(Dropout(0.9))
    final_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    final_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    final_model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    final_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    adam_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a binary classification, `binary crossentropy` is the loss function you are looking for.

Achieving a well generalizing model includes more than just the right loss function choice (Preprocessing Data, Finding a proper Network Architecture, Finding the right hyper parameter choice, ...).

You can find a discussion about generalization of Deep Learning Models here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365778/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-generalize-well

Comment: Thanks @Yannick Funk I have used the same but model doesn't generalize well! Maximum validation accuracy was < 70% . Thats why I posted question here

Comment: @mr_swap Achieving a good generalization is a multidimensional problem which includes preprocessing, hyperparameter optimization, optimization algorithm choice and so on, there are many good articles about generalization and the loss function should not be the problem here. If you think my answer is satisfactory: accept it as the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `binary crossentropy` function. The loss function depends on the output, not how the data looks like. This problem is probably "Overfitting", and I suggest some changes:

- Try using other activation functions, i.e. "tanh"
- Try decreasing Dropout. 90% is too high. Typically 0.1-0.6 is ideal, but there's no restriction.
- You can try normalizing or standardizing the data before training.

Comment: No! data is perfectly balanced! @AerysS

Comment: What's this? `The feature data is quite sparse i.e. lots of zeros and rare 1's`

Comment: Seeing your model code, that is not because of the loss function. Your model runs into other problems, which could be "overfitting".

Comment: For each sample not all 2048 features found active (1), There are average 5 to 80 active features per samples, rest features are 0.

Comment: @mr_swap look at the link i provided in my answer and inform yourself about generalization. Note that your question originally was a different one and has been answered twice here

Comment: @YannickFunk lol the author changes the question rapidly that it is now 3 different questions in a post.

Comment: @AerysS Ironically that its mister swap haha